# Make Action Button Blue

Tags: adaptive-cards

I am using Adaptive Cards 1.2 and displaying these cards in MS Teams. I want to set the color as blue for the action button. I tried setting Style property but no luck.

card.Actions = new List()
                    {
                        new AdaptiveSubmitAction
                        {
                            Title = "Confirm",
                            DataJson = "{ \"Type\": \"find-usr-common-meeting-slot\" }",
                            Style="positive",
                    }
                 };

Answer (score 1):

Teams Does not support Card action button styling in cards. This is by design. The same is mentioned as a note here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions?tabs=json#adaptive-cards-actions

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure but based on the designer: https://www.adaptivecards.io/designer/ , when you select either MS Teams Light or Dark it just ignores the style property.

Colors for Buttons are based on the Host. As far as I remember, MS Teams just wants the buttons to look the same so you can't change the style.